# Stripe, Retrieve Card Info from Event

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

This was working for me on one account and today I added my listener to a new Stripe account and now it is no longer working. When a customer adds a new payment method to their account, the event `customer.source.created` is fired. Here is my code that WAS working (this is an excerpt):

```
<?php 
if($event->type == 'customer.source.created') {
  $cardID = $event_json->data->object->id;
  $customerID = $event_json->data->object->customer;
  $brand = $event_json->data->object->brand;
  $last4 = $event_json->data->object->last4;
  $exp_month = $event_json->data->object->exp_month;
  $exp_year = $event_json->data->object->exp_year;
}
?>
```

Here is a sample Stripe JSON response:

```
    {
  "id": "evt_1DLkAh2Y54K5YG39Lku1hJ1G",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2018-09-24",
  "created": 1539664123,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "card_1DLkAf2Y54K5YG39C0jMpCOj",
      "object": "card",
      "address_city": null,
      "address_country": null,
      "address_line1": null,
      "address_line1_check": null,
      "address_line2": null,
      "address_state": null,
      "address_zip": null,
      "address_zip_check": null,
      "brand": "JCB",
      "country": "JP",
      "customer": "cus_DnCcf39Nqp4RwF",
      "cvc_check": "pass",
      "dynamic_last4": null,
      "exp_month": 12,
      "exp_year": 2024,
      "fingerprint": "t56gZmsPg6ztkHFH",
      "funding": "credit",
      "last4": "0000",
      "metadata": {
      },
      "name": null,
      "tokenization_method": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": false,
  "pending_webhooks": 2,
  "request": {
    "id": "req_L9pvt2RR3VSZoG",
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "customer.source.created"
}
```

The Stripe response code is 200.  I have other events in my listener like `charge.succeeded` that are working just fine with pretty much the same coding methods. Right now, I can't get the `$cardID` to echo. So I'm wondering if Stripe changed something recently. I am running the latest version in Webhooks.  I did try to revert to an older version but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was a very stupid issue I didn't catch. The stripe account that I set up today was in an older version and there was an update available. I didn't catch that because I was working in test mode and you can only upgrade in live mode.

So, after upgrading, everything works perfectly. Hours of wasted time and something so simple.